# Qfield photo functionality - Increment filename

Tags: photos, qfield

The question is in the title, when I use the photo functionality in Qfield, it stores the pictures in a DCIM folder, and the filenames are tagged with the time and date. I would like to be able to name the jpg file with the ID of my station.

Also, is there a way to take several pictures on one station, if so how would one do to increment filenames with ID_Station+1 ?

Answer (score 1):

As with the new version of QField (1.6 onwards) and QGIS 3.14, you can set an expression as default for your picture name. You need the QGIS plugin "QField Sync" to set this expression.

For further reference have a look at the release notes:

https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v1.6.0

Comment: Have you gotten this to work? Using Qfield 1.6.2 and QFieldSync 3.2.2 with QGIS 3.10, I don't seem to have the option mentioned on the page you linked.

Comment: it only works with QGIS 3.14 onwards - I will edit my answer accordingly!